# Aligning SVG within parent

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm learning SVG and getting a bit of help from here. This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/C8d34/6/

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"> /* this here */
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

How can I align my circle so it sits horizontally aligned within the blue box and is aligned to the bottom vertically. I believe it is something to do with:

```
x="50" y="0"
```

But I haven't had any luck with that, it still doesn't sit in the right place.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us how it's **supposed** to look? An SVG element is just like any other and can be positioned with margins and positioning values.

Comment: I want the SVG stage to be able to take up the whole blue area, but then I want the circle itself to be 50% size and be bottom aligned. I have set it up so the SVG takes up 100% of the blue but how do I then make the cicle 50% of that area rather than 100% http://jsfiddle.net/8mtFC/4/embedded/result/

Comment: You mean like this - http://jsfiddle.net/8mtFC/17/ I've stripped out all the extra cruft that isn't need to make the fiddle easier to read

Comment: Thank you for that. Well kind of, that is the end effect that I want. But I want to put other SVG's in the blue box too, some are bigger, some are smaller. My understanding was I make the SVG style the full 100%, and then apply the 50% style only to the circle within, that way when I add another circle I can make that say 75%?

Comment: You should really explain the **full** problem if you're going to throw in additional complexities once you get an answer to your actual original question.

Comment: Sorry Paulie, it seemed like quite a lot to ask / explain in one go, and I didnt realise there was more than one approach to aligning and sizing

Comment: You need to look into svg `defs` and `use`....This is loo large a subject to go into here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
svg {
    height: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 50%;
}
```

Try this. Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C8d34/10/

Comment: Thank you. This sits on the bottom right rather than bottom middle but it's pretty close. My concern is about using negative translates, is there not a better way?

Comment: this is the best way, maybe you have to use prefixes for translate? i'v updated my answer

Comment: you are missing `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Comment: I still don't think this is the right approach to the problem. I think it is more to do with this is it not? ```<g transform="translate(20,2.5) rotate(10)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10"/>
</g>```

Answer (score 0):

```
svg {
vertical-align: middle;
display:inline-block;
}
```